# import txt file in SAS

Tags: import, sas

I have a text file with comments that I need to import in SAS.
the text file look like this

```
# DATA1
#
# -- 
#     
ID  nbmiss  x1  x2  x3  x4 
1   1           45  38  47 
2   0       37  45  39  51 
3   3                   58 
4   4               
5   0       68  45  73  76 
6   2               52  48
```

my output in SAS must look like this

```
Obs x1 x2 x3 x4 
1    . 45 38 47 
2   37 45 39 51 
3    .  .  . 58 
4    .  .  .  . 
5   68 45 73 76 
6    .  . 52 48
```

here is what I did. It gives me what I am looking for but it's long. I think there is a more simple way.

```
proc import datafile= 'Z:\bloc1data\data\data1.txt'
            out=class
            dbms=dlm
            replace;
       datarow=6;
     delimiter='09'x;
run;
proc print data = work.class label;
var VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6;
label VAR3='x1' VAR4='x2' VAR5='x3' VAR6='x4';
run;
```

My question is how to have the same output in a simplify way?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that's doing the import:

```
proc import datafile= 'Z:\bloc1data\data\data1.txt'
            out=class
            dbms=dlm
            replace;
       datarow=6;
     delimiter='09'x;
run;
```

That seems pretty short to me.  Four actual lines of code, around a hundred characters...  The equivalent code in the data step is basically the same.

```
data want;
  infile 'z:\bloc1data\data\data1.txt' dlm='09'x dsd firstobs=6;
  input id nbmiss x1 x2 x3 x4;
run;
```

That file unfortunately doesn't work well for determining the names automatically (which otherwise you could do). DBMS=DLM does not have a `namerow` option to tell it where to pick names up from, so you would need to preprocess the file to remove the extraneous lines to do that.  You're welcome to ask as a separate question how to do so, but it's not "simpler" than the above (though it is probably "better").